# Как умножить экземпляра класса на число в эллиптических кривых над конечными полями?

Tags: python, математика, blockchain

### Ошибка умножения экземпляра класса на число в эллиптических кривых над конечными полями.

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, из-за которой не могу перемножить вышеописанное.
Вводимый код для тестирования:

```
prime = 223
a = FieldElement(num=0, prime=prime)
b = FieldElement(num=7, prime=prime)
x = FieldElement(num=47, prime=prime)
y = FieldElement(num=71, prime=prime)
p1 = Point(x, y, a, b)
print(8*p1)
```

Перегрузки операторов умножения и сложения описаны в коде класса FieldElement:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
    if self.prime != other.prime:
        raise TypeError('Cannot add numbers in different Fields')
    num = (self.num + other.num) % self.prime
    return self.__class__(num, self.prime)

    def __mul__(self, other):
    if self.prime != other.prime:
        raise TypeError('Cannot multiply numbers in different Fields')
    mul = (self.num * other.num) % self.prime
    return self.__class__(mul, self.prime)
```

В классе Point:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
    if self.a != other.a or self.b != other.b:
        raise TypeError(f'{self} {other} are not on the same Curve')
    if self.x is None:
        return other
    if other.x is None:
        return self
    if self.x == other.x and self.y != other.y:  # vertical invertibility
        return self.__class__(None, None, self.a, self.b)
    if self.x != other.x:  # tangent
        s = (other.y - self.y) / (other.x - self.x)
        x = s ** 2 - self.x - other.x
        y = s * (self.x - x) - self.y
        return self.__class__(x, y, self.a, self.b)

    if self == other:  # p1=p2
        s = (3 * self.x ** 2 + self.a) / (2 * self.y)
        x = s ** 2 - 2 * self.x
        y = s * (self.x - x) - self.y
        return self.__class__(x, y, self.a, self.b)

    if self == other and self.y == 0 * self.x:  # infinity vertical tangent with 0 divider
        return self.__class__(None, None, self.a, self.b)

    def __rmul__(self, coef):
        current = self  
        result = self.__class__(None, None, self.a, self.b)  # <2>
        while coef:
            if coef & 1:  
                result += current
            current += current  
            coef >>= 1  
        return result
```

Ну и сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File test.py line 135, in <module>
       print(8*p1)
    File ecc.py, line 109, in __rmul__
       current += current  
    File ecc.py, line 95, in __add__
       s = (3 * self.x ** 2 + self.a) / (2 * self.y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'FieldElement'
```

**Благодарю за помощь!**

Comment: у вас опрелён метод `__mul__` - это левое умножение вида `el * num`, когда объект стоит слева. Вы же умножаете на объект справа `3 * self.x`. Для этого вам нужно определить метод `__rmul__`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Все получилось